# Tao Analysis 6.4.3 help with proof verification involving limsup,liminf

Tags: real-analysis

This isn’t the full exercise, but this is the part that I am stuck on and need help verifying.

WTS: Let $(a_n)^\infty_{n=m}$ be a sequence of real numbers and $L^-$ and $L^+$ be its limit inferior and limit superior respectively(They can take on $\infty$ or $-\infty$). Show that $L^-\le L^+$.

FSOC, assume $L^->L^+$, then since $L^+$ is the limit superior or equivalently $inf(a_n^+)^\infty_{n=m}$, there exists $N \ge m$ st $L^->a_N^+$

Using a similar argument of $L^-$ being the limit inferior, there exists $K \ge m$ st $a_K^->a_N^+$

If $N\ge K$, then $a_N^->a_K^-$ since $(a_N^-)$ is an increasing sequence. If $K > N$, then $a_N^+>a_K^+$ since $(a_n^+)$ is an decreasing sequence. In both case, combining with the earlier inequality of $a_K^->a_N^+$ we have that the infinium of a sequence is greater than its own supremum which is the desired contradiction. $\square$

If there is anything I can clarify, do let me know

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: When you post in a forum like this, you need to realize that your audience is broad, and therefore you should be careful to avoid abbreviations and notations that are not widely spread. What is "WTS", or "FSOC"? What are $a_n^+$ and $a_n^-$? While I can make guesses at the latter three, and the first seems pointless, whatever it means, it isn't nice to make people who you want to assist you to have to guess your meaning.